# C# EF Core reference different tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I´ve got 3 models where one has an XML-Content Property, which contains one of the other Models. Now I want to reference table Person with the other two tables and sometimes select the entity from table Person from table Company or "Registered association".

Here my models

```
public class Person
{
    [Key, IgnoreDataMember, XmlIgnore]
    public ulong Id { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastNake { get; set; }
}

public class Company 
{
    [Key, IgnoreDataMember, XmlIgnore]
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RegisterCode { get; set; }
}

public class RegisteredAssociation 
{
    [Key, IgnoreDataMember, XmlIgnore]
    public ulong Id { get; set; }

    public Name { get; set; }
    public uint Members { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want a reference from Company or RegisteredAssociation in Person but a Person is only one a CompanyMember or RegisteredAssociation Member, which is represend in the Content Field. And sometimes I want to select a Person from Company (a Company has many Persons) but also don´t want to add a Company-Field in the person which can be null.

Comment: You'll need the FK fields in the database table. Though you could hide them from your data model by using shadow properties. You *could* define person as a "table-per-heirachy" and store a `CompanyPerson` or `AssociationPerson` in the same table. But that seems over complicated to me. But I think the right answer is to store the company and association in the same table.

Comment: Is this really related to the SQL _language_? I see no SQL above. Do you expect a SQL answer?